# Non-exhaustive warning on sealed class match

Tags: scala

Given

```
sealed class UnionKey private (val i: Int) {
  def encode(stream: XdrDataOutputStream) = stream.writeInt(i)
}

object UnionKey {
  def decode(stream: XdrDataInputStream): UnionKey = stream.readInt() match {
    case 1 => ONE
    case 2 => TWO
    case 3 => OFFER
    case i => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"UnionKey value $i is invalid")
  }

  case object ONE extends UnionKey(1)
  case object TWO extends UnionKey(2)
  case object OFFER extends UnionKey(3)
}
```

I get a non-exhaustive match warning when compiling:

```
object MyUnion {
  def decode(stream: XdrDataInputStream): MyUnion = UnionKey.decode(stream) match {
    case UnionKey.ONE => MyUnionOne(stream.readInt)
    case UnionKey.TWO => MyUnionTwo(stream.readInt, Foo.decode(stream))
    case UnionKey.OFFER => MyUnionOffer
  }
}
```

The warning:

```
myxdr/MyUnion.scala:25: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: UnionKey()
  def decode(stream: XdrDataInputStream): MyUnion = UnionKey.decode(stream) match {
                                                                   ^
one warning found
```

As there are no other instantiations of `UnionKey`. Why do I get this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that even though `UnionKey` is `sealed`, it is still a `class`, which does not prevent new instances of it from being created. This means that you have to handle the general case of `UnionKey` in your `match`. Making the constructor `private` does not help, because Scala compiler still won't be able to ensure that you don't create other instances in your code - it would require executing your code for the most general case, which the compiler obviously won't do.

What you can do is to change `class` to `abstract class`:

```
sealed abstract class UnionKey private (val i: Int)
```

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, and it is possible to prove statically that there could be no other instances than the derived case objects, therefore there will be no warning. Here is a toy example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ue3obXY9SUOmLSKRFw4mcg Try removing `abstract` in it, for example, and you will see the warning again.

Comment: The standard idiom for Closed Algebraic Data Types is to use a `sealed trait` as the top of the hierarchy, which will not exhibit this problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is not always convenient because traits do not have parameters.